# vba timeline filter

Tags: excel, vba, timeline, slicers

I'm trying to use the timeline slicer in Excel to update the axis on a chart.  For example, the timeline slicer allows you to pick days/months/quarters/years.  I don't want to have multiple charts showing each time frame.  I want to be able to create a timeline slicer that allows you to pick days and the charts horizontal axis will update and show days.  Than pick months on the timeline slices and the axis on the charts switch to show the month totals.

Would this need to be done in VBA?  Is there a way to connect a chart's axis to the filter period settings on the timeline slicer?

Please advise.

Comment: Is the date column grouped on the pivot table?

Comment: that is one way to do it but i would need several different groupings (months/quarters/years) and this would require multiple charts.  Would like to have a timeline slicer control the axis of one single chart to display all period types selected by the timeline

Answer (score 0):

The Excel chart axis shows the data as it appears in the source table. If the data in the source table is showing days, then the chart axis will show days. If the source data shows months, then the axis units will be months.

So, if you want to change the axis units, you need to change the pivot table. The timeline is only a filter tool for the time period.

The behaviour you describe will require code.

Comment: I haven't been able to find many examples of VBA code and timeline.  Any guidelines would be greatly appreciated.  thanks.

Comment: @jdood did you find a solution?